# iOS triggers wrong viewport height on reisze

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I am having trouble while debugging an iOS issue in Safari (latest version). The problem is that iOS triggers the resize event correctly, but the value of the viewport height `$(window).height()` will be the old value inside the resize function. So when the toolbar is in the "mini-view" (after scrolling down) I am getting the value like if it's the "big-view" including buttons in the toolbar.

Is this a known issue or is there any workaround?

Comment: use plain javascript window.innerHeight in resize event, it helps